# Pass arguments via file and via command line

Tags: python, argparse

How could I use `argparse` to pass a .txt file with arguments (say epochs, size, data) as well as arguments through the command line? I would like to do `python main.py @args.txt --arg1 1 --arg2 543` where args.txt has more arguments to be parsed. However, I try something like this:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(fromfile_prefix_chars='@')  
parser.add_argument('-e', '--epochs', type=int) 
parser.add_argument('-s', '--size',  type=int) 
parser.add_argument('-d', '--data')
parser.add_argument('--arg1')
parser.add_argument('--arg1')

args = parser.parse_args()
epochs = args.epochs
arg1 = args.arg1
```

I get the error that arg1 is not a valid argument.

Comment: Add the content of `args.txt` to the question

Comment: And the exact error message you get